# Cannot find my data folder when I export my project as jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I tried to export my eclipse java project as a runnable jar file. In my main function I have to read data file from the data folder in my project as following:

```
List<Data> trainDataSet = readDataFile("data/BTrain.arff");
```

I build my data folder as source folder. But when I run java -jar myproject.jar
It gives me this error:

```
File not found: data/ATrain.arff
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StreamTokenizer.<init>(StreamTokenizer.java:248)
    at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader$ArffReader.<init>(ArffLoader.java:135)
    at weka.core.Instances.<init>(Instances.java:126)
    at project4.Project4.readDataFile(Project4.java:29)
    at project4.Project4.testPrimalPerceptron(Project4.java:51)
    at project4.Project4.main(Project4.java:145)
```

But this works well when I run the project as a java application in eclipse

This is the structure of my project,
[image]

Any idea on it? Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818429/referencing-data-files-in-jars and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995767/need-help-accessing-data-file-in-jar-file

Comment: @AndyThomas First you need to explain how to put them in the jar. Only then you can go to explaining how to load them from the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Think about your jar as a zip archive (it actually is a zip archive, try to open it with 7zip!) you can put whatever files and folders in it when you export your project from eclipse.

After you've done that, you can load resources from your Jar with

```
private static final String DATA_BTRAIN_ARFF = "data/BTrain.arff";
....
InputStream inputStream  = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(DATA_BTRAIN_ARFF);
.....
```